# Create a Stripe invoice via Zapier

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks, zapier

I need to create a Stripe invoice from a Spreadsheet. I'm using Zapier to automate it but I'm having an issue with it and need help with POST functionality. I need help with Step 3.

Zapier logic:

✅ Step 1 - Get data after a specific row in the spreadsheet is updated
✅ Step 2 - Create a customer in Stripe
 Step 3 - Create a Stripe invoice (using customer id from Step 2)
such parameters should be included (description, amount, item, payment_methods )
⏳ (didn't start) Step 4 - Get a Payment Link
⏳ (didn't start) Step 5 - Update a spreadsheet with the invoice number and Payment Link

I'm using POST in Webhooks by Zapier. But I'm getting an error when I'm adding a dynamic customer id.
`The app returned "No such customer: 'XXX'".`

When I'm using a static customer id, I have a different issue:
`The app returned "Nothing to invoice for customer".`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAGS2.png)

If anyone has a [similar guide](https://community.zapier.com/show-tell-5/guide-how-to-create-dynamic-stripe-payment-links-14249), that would be great :)

Comment: For the "No such customer: 'XXX'" error, are you using the exact same API key as you used to create the customer?

Comment: Correct. API KEY is not an issue as I see some activity in the Stripe Logs after each POST

Comment: You are getting the second error because there are no invoice items on the customer. Basically, Stripe has two flows, either create the invoice first and then its items, or create the items then the invoice. This doc shows how to create invoice items first: https://stripe.com/docs/invoicing/integration

Comment: That doc actually doesn't show what I was trying to show now that I look at it. Basically, when creating an invoice, there is a `pending_invoice_items_behavior` argument. You can set it to `include` if you have already created invoice items on the customer that you want to bill or you can pass `exclude` if you want to add all invoice items after it is has been created https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/create#create_invoice-pending_invoice_items_behavior

Comment: @Pompey, pending_invoice_items_behavior: exclude - helped to resolve the problem. Thanks a lot!